# issue with debounceTime rxjs operator and http request on input keyup function

Tags: angular, typescript, http, rxjs, angular7

i'm trying to implement server side search in angular7. I found some code to implement this but unfortunately this is not working as required. When i search a string it send multiple http request but it should be only one http request. here is my code.

```
    fromEvent(this.simpleSearchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      switchMap((search: any) => {
        return this.usersService.simpleUserSearch(search.target.value);
      })
    ).subscribe(res => {
      this.queryUsers = res.result.data;
      console.log('User Name is :' + res);

    }); 
  }
```

Comment: This code will invoke multiple http requests if you use more than 500 milliseconds between two button clicks , but I am guessing you are aware of that. Besides that, your code looks correct as far as I can see.

Comment: You're trying to implement live search, right? For manual search you might want to listen to form submit event.

Comment: @Kos yes, i'm trying to implement live search i want response on keyup or input event.

Comment: @SnorreDan i have changed time from 500 ms to 300 ms but i get same issue with it. I don't know how it will work.

Comment: You need to increase it, not decrease it. 300 is only 0.3 seconds, so it means that if a user uses more that 0.3 seconds between two button clicks, an http request will occur. Try setting it to 2000 for example, that would mean 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a rough example, based on your code. Take a note of logging and try playing with timings for `debounceTime` and `delay` to see how it affects the behavior:

```js
var { timer, fromEvent, of } = rxjs;
var { debounceTime, map, switchMap, delay, tap } = rxjs.operators;


var theInput = document.getElementById('the-input');

fromEvent(theInput, 'input').pipe(
  map(e=>e.target.value)     // read value from input
  , tap(console.info)        // realtime input log
  , debounceTime(1000)       // time till reaction
  // mocking long server request {{{
  , switchMap(q => of(q.toUpperCase()).pipe(
      tap(q => console.info('[requested]', q)),
      delay(2000),         // server ping time
      tap(q => console.info('[returned]', q))
  ))
  // }}}
).subscribe(res => {
  console.log('Result is: ' + res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>

<input
  id="the-input"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Start typing"
  />
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but rather a detailed playground example to explain what @SnorreDan meant

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I found somewhere and it's working perfectly I used lodash rather than using RXJS library

**Steps**

**1. Import debounce in your component ts file.**

> import { debounce } from 'lodash';

**2. Make a private property**

> private debouncedFunction: any = null;

**3. Use debouncedFunction in your function**

```
 search(event: any) {
    if (this.debouncedFunction) {
      this.debouncedFunction.cancel();
    }
    this.debouncedFunction = debounce(() => {
      console.log(event); // console.log will print event value after 1s of stop writing
    }, 1000);



 this.debouncedFunction();
  }
```